# Scifi movie where an alien has a baby on a bus

Tags: story-identification, aliens, b-movies

Trying to help a friend find an old sci-fi movie. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as we've searched for hours and come up with nothing.

> I need help guys. There is this absolutely horrible sci-fi movie I saw
>   as a child and i can't for the life of me remember what it was called.
>   All I can remember is at one point near the end, there was a bus load
>   of aliens and one of them was pregnant and in labor and she gave birth
>   in the back of the bus, which caused the other aliens to flee the bus
>   and it caused a nasty wave of goo and amniotic fluid to come
>   pouring/flooding out of the bus
>
> It's super gross and that's why I remember that part so vividly. But
>   it was a group of aliens that all looked different and they were
>   trying to escape something. They were on earth in the country
>   somewhere.
>
> It was an 70s/80s movie. I remember turning it on in the middle and
>   then my mom walked in during the birthing scene and freaked out
>   wondering what i was watching and she made me turn it off. This has
>   been haunting me since childhood ^ It's a B or maybe even a C Rated
>   Sci-fi movie. I think the aliens were hiding on a farm or something
>   and there were humans trying to get them back to some ship before the
>   other humans came to kill them. It was SUPER weird, so of course I was
>   TOTALLY INTO IT, but mom had to ruin my shine.

Answer (score 10):

The OP posted this comment:

> It turned out to be Basket Case 3. Thanks for your suggestion though!

I think this is the relevant scene (from [Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basket_Case_3%3A_The_Progeny)):

> With Hal incapacitated Belial is drugged to calm him down and the birth of his and Eve's twelve children is overseen by Little Hal, Hal and Granny Ruth's multi-armed and blob-like prodigy son.

And, by the way, your mother was right to stop you from watching it. Judging by the synopsis very shortly after this scene; it is *not* suitable for children.

Answer (score 9):

If you turn the bus into a station wagon, this is exactly one of the scenes from *Men In Black* (1997, Tommy Lee Jones as Agent J, Will Smith as Agent K, Rip Torn as Agent Zed; also Vince D'Onofrio as Edgar/The Bug) -- new agent K gets roped into delivering (well, catching) a baby from an octopoid mother, while the family is illegally fleeing New York; during this, J is questioning the father, finding out that the word is out that something terrible is coming.

Comment: You're right! J is played by Tommy Lee Jones and K by Will Smith

Comment: It turned out to be Basket Case 3. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Cool, glad you found it.  You may as well write it up as an answer for your question (yes, that's not just permitted, but encouraged here) and, when permitted, accept it, so we have the correct answer *as an answer*.  These comments are likely to be removed over time, but answers won't be.